# Python class that automatically appends values to existing attribute OR creates and fills new attribute

Tags: python, class, dictionary, spyder, attr

My goal here is to be able to create nested dictionaries that have attributes that hold lists of values. For example, I want to be able to do something like this:

```
mydict['Person 1']['height'].vals = [23, 25, 32]
mydict['Person 2']['weight'].vals = [100, 105, 110]
mydict['Person 2']['weight'].excel_locs ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']
```

So, for each "person" I can keep track of multiple things I might have data on, such as height and weight. The attribute I'm calling 'vals' is just a list of values for heights or weights. Importantly, I want to be able to keep track of things like where the raw data came from, such as its location in an Excel spreadsheet.

Here's what I am currently working off of:

```
import collections
class Vals:
    def add(self, list_of_vals=[], attr_name=[]):
        setattr(self, attr_name, val)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.__dict__)
mydict = collections.defaultdict(Vals)
```

So, I want to be able to add new keys as needed, such as mydict['Person 10']['test scores'], and then create a new attribute such as "vals" if it doesn't exist, but also append new values to it if it does.

Example of what I want to achieve:

```
mydict['Person 10']['test scores'].add([10, 20, 30], 'vals')
```

Which should allow mydictmydict['Person 10']['test scores'].vals to return [10, 20, 30]

But then I also want to be able to append to this list later on if needed, such that using .add again append to the existing list. For example, mydict['Person 10']['test scores'].add([1, 2, 3], 'vals') should then allow me to return [10, 20, 30, 1, 2, 3] from mydict['Person 10']['test scores'].vals.

I'm still very much getting used to object oriented programming, classes, etc. I am very open to better strategies that might exist for achieving my goal, which is just a nested dictionary structure which I find convenient for holding data.

If we just modify the Vals class above, it needs a way to determine whether an attribute exists. If so, create and populate it with list_of_vals, otherwise append to the existing list

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what I understand, you want something that you can conveniently hold data. I would actually build a class instead of a nested dictionary, because this allows for an easier way to see how everything works together (and it also helps organize everything!).

```
class Person(object):
    """__init__() functions as the class constructor"""
    def __init__(self, name=None, testScores=None):
        self.name = name
        self.testScores = testScores


# make a list of class Person(s)
personList = []
personList.append(Person("Person 1",[10,25,32]))
personList.append(Person("Person 2",[22,37,45]))

print("Show one particular item:")
print(personList[0].testScores)
personList[0].testScores.append(50)
print(personList[0].testScores)

print(personList[1].name)
```

Basically, the Person class is what holds all of the data for an instance of it. If you want to add different types of data, you would add a parameter to the **init**() function like this:

```
def __init__(self, name=None, testScores=None, weight = None):
    self.name = name
    self.testScores = testScores
    self.weight = weight
```

You can edit the values just like you would a variable.

If this isn't what you are looking for, or you are confused, I am willing to try to help you more.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that using a `Person` class is a better solution here. It's a more abstract & intuitive way to represent a the concept, which will make your code easier to work with.

Check this out:

```
class Person():

    # Define a custom method for retrieving attributes
    def __getattr__(self, attr_name):
        # If the attribute exists, setdefault will return it.
        # If it doesn't yet exist, it will set it to an empty
        # dictionary, and then return it.
        return self.__dict__.setdefault(attr_name, {})

carolyn = Person()
carolyn.name["value"] = "Carolyn" 
carolyn.name["excel_loc"] = "A1"

print(carolyn.name)
# {"value": "Carolyn", "excel_loc": "A1"}

maria = Person()
print(maria.name)
# {}
```

Then collecting people into a dictionary is easy:

```
people = {
    "carolyn": carolyn,
    "maria": maria
}
people["Ralph"] = Person()
people["Ralph"].name["value"] = "Ralph"
```

You've also made a tricky mistake in defining the `add` method:

```
def add(self, list_of_vals=[], attr_name=[]):
    ...
```

In Python, you never want to set an empty list as a default variable. Because of the way they're stored under the hood, your default variable will reference the *same list* every time, instead of creating a new, empty list each time.
Here's a common workaround:

```
def add(self, list_of_vals=None, attr_name=None):
    list_of_vals = list_of_vals or []
    attr_name = attr_name or []
    ...
```